# import all CSV files in folder

Tags: vba, excel

I used this code to import all CSV files in "Emails" folder but the results >> from row 1 to 102 they put the file name in four columns then shifting the emails.how can i just import the csv file content without file name (folder contains 4 CSV files "Email1,Email2,Email3,Email4")

---

```
Sub ImportCSVsWithReference()
'UpdatebyKutoolsforExcel20151214 // Vertically
Dim xSht  As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim xFile As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False

xStrPath = ("D:\Excel\Learning Excel VBA\Outlook VBA\Emails")

If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub

Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\" & "*.csv")

Do While xFile <> ""
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
    Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
    Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    xWb.Close False
    xFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox "no files csv", , "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub
```

**results**

```
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  Email1
Email4  Email3  Email2  "From:  Montaser Abu Roumi <msroumi@gmail.com>"
Email4  Email3  Email2  "Sent:  Sunday"
Email4  Email3  Email2  "To:    msroumi@hotmail.com"
Email4  Email3  Email2  "Subject:   5896321574"
Email4  Email3  Email2  
Email4  Email3  Email2  GOPS / hold CC 7th circle 
Email4  Email3  "From:  Montaser Abu Roumi <msroumi@gmail.com>" 
Email4  Email3  "Sent:  Sunday"  June 17
Email4  Email3  "To:    msroumi@hotmail.com"    
Email4  Email3  "Subject:   1505264896" 
Email4  Email3      
Email4  Email3  GTW / Aramex    
Email4  "From:  Montaser Abu Roumi <msroumi@gmail.com>"     
Email4  "Sent:  Sunday"  June 17     2018 5:20 PM
Email4  "To:    msroumi@hotmail.com"        
Email4  "Subject:   5879658396"     
Email4          
Email4  GTW / Al Dar for clearance      
"From:  Montaser Abu Roumi <msroumi@gmail.com>"         
"Sent:  Sunday"  June 17     2018 5:19 PM   
"To:    msroumi@hotmail.com"            
"Subject:   1801504685"
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Is filling the selected range with the sheet name, which for a csv file, is the file name. Hence why you end up with a column filled with the file names!

Have you tried running the code with that line removed?

In fact, try changing this ...

```
Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

To

```
xSht.Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Comment: the loop didnt copy each CSV file to the sheet, it just keeps the final CSV file copied, ( i guess it over wright copying files so the last file just copied)

Answer (score 0):

I see.  Ok, consider this.

```
' Merge data from multiple sheets into separate sheets
Sub R_AnalysisMerger2()
    Dim WSA As Worksheet
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim SelectedFiles As Variant
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, vDB As Variant, rngT As Range
    Dim vFn, myFn As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsEmpty(SelectedFiles) Then Exit Sub

    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
        vFn = Split(FileName, "\")
        myFn = vFn(UBound(vFn))
        myFn = Replace(myFn, ".csv", "")
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(FileName, Format:=2)
        Set WSA = bookList.Sheets(1)
        vDB = WSA.UsedRange
        bookList.Close (0)
        Set Ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        ActiveSheet.Name = myFn
        Ws.Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

' Merge data from multime files into one sheet.
Sub R_AnalysisMerger()
    Dim WSA As Worksheet
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, vDB As Variant, rngT As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Ws.UsedRange.Clear
    'change folder path of excel files here
    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", MultiSelect:=True)


    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(FileName, Format:=2)
        Set WSA = bookList.Sheets(1)
        With WSA
            vDB = .UsedRange
            Set rngT = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
            If rngT.Row = 2 Then Set rngT = Ws.Range("a1")
            rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

            bookList.Close (0)
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Ws.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

You may want to consider using Python or R to do the task.  Just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

The AddIn from the link below will do exactly what you want.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]

Comment: thanks Ryguy72 for helping but i cant use or install any AddIn as it is a project for work and computers needs admin approvals to install any program or AddIn, i need to do it all VBA,